# Очень долгий ответ

Tags: python, asyncio, python-3.7, uvicorn, fastapi

Я пишу на [FastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi)

У меня есть сервис. Сразу после запуска мой сервис отвечает за секунду. Через несколько минут после запуска, мой сервис отвечает за 10 мс. Откуда берётся такая проблема?

Примечание. Это свойство обслуживания от [FastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi), так как я измеряю время выполнения моего обработчика в моем коде. Это 10 мс

---

В рамках моего сервиса, было измерено:

```
import datetime

# Service initialisation

async def my_handler():
    t = datetime.datetime.now()
    # any actions
    print((datetime.datetime.now() - t).total_seconds())

# Service running
```

В ответ я получаю, в среднем: **0.002 +- 0.001**. В таком случае, делаем вывод, что проблема именно в [FastAPI](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi).

Если я использую постман (оцениваю на глаз курлом). Порядок времени ответа равен 1 секунде. Спустя какое-то время, это проблема исчезает и всё нормализуется. Время ответа становится ожидаемым.

Comment: Прогрев коннектов к базе? Прогрев базы данных?

Comment: Исключено, поскольку я тестировал отдельно код (замерил время и там всё 
 в порядке).

Comment: Кэширование никто не отменял наверное...

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич При чём тут кэширование?

Comment: @hedgehogues а при чем тут fastAPI :) Ваш вопрос на столько общий, что скорее можно получить общий ответ, чем у кого то "решение" внезапно совпадёт случайным образом с Вашим.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич посмотрите правки

Comment: фастапи такая жуткая штука.... ничего хорошего там не нашел кроме обозревателя апи из браузера.

Comment: @eri чем же она жуткая? Многие вещи там делаются проще, чем на фласке и в разы быстрее. Некоторых вещей нельзя сделать.

Comment: @hedgehogues 5 строчек с перегрузом на 5 сущностей вместо трех. копипасты там километры...

Comment: @eri примеры пожалуйста

Comment: Это уже офтоп) а по сути дела - пробовал запустить на профилировщике? Нарисовать какой метод сколько кушает. Может сбор моделей к пидантику в кеш?

Comment: @eri внутрь фастапи не залазил.

Comment: Хоть cProfile попробуй